# I'm trying to run a VHDL code on Vivado [else clause after check for clock not supported]

Tags: vhdl, simulation, clock, vivado

It's my first go so I'm sorry if it's a simple problem

```
process(m_start, flag_start, state_counter, count_7)
    begin
        if rising_edge(m_start) then flag_start <= '1';
        elsif (state_counter = H and count_7 = "111") then flag_start <= '0';
        end if;
end process;
```

I'm trying to make a 111 detector that counts the first 111 and two 111s in a row and a counter that counts the number of 111 and resets when it hits 7

this is the state diagram

[image]

The exact error statement is
"else clause after the check for clock not supported"

Comment: There is a big difference between what can be written in VHDL and what can be synthesized by vivado. Please read the vivado synthesis guide on how to properly write synthesizable vhdl.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to mix up clocked construct in a combinatorial process. Your VHDL is not really synthesizable this way and would also create latches, that you strictly would want to avoid (in most cases).

One problem is that you want your process to act on a rising edge of m_start, but you are not doing this in a clocked process. Plus, the value of your assigned flag_start would be latched and not actually registered properly. I suggest reading up again on clocked vs. combinatorial processes and how to detect rising edges.

About the error message, apparently VHDL or in that case the Vivado synthesizer simply doesnt allow anything to follow the rising_edge if (or ifelse) statement, because it is only used in clocked processes. And in those processes everything depends on this rising clock edge (except maybe an asynchronous reset before).

You can use the code below as an inspiration, but I suggest you think about what behaviour you exactly want and also understand what you VHDL code does. Here I use another signal to register m_start to be able to detect a rising edge.

```
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    -- register m_start to use it in edge detection
    m_start_d <= m_start;
    -- If m_start is 1 and m_start_d is 0 it means there was a rising edge
    if m_start = '1' and m_start_d = '0' then
      flag_start <= '1';
    elsif (state_counter = H and count_7 = "111") then
      flag_start <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score -3):

A clocked process must always have one of these formats:

```
process(reset, clock)
begin
    if reset='1' then
        your_signal <= '0'; -- or another reset value
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then
        your_signal <= ... 
        -- here you can add another if:
        if <condition> then
            ....
        elsif <condition> then
            ....
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

or

```
process(clock)
begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
        your_signal <= ... 
    end if;
end process;
```

You are not allowed to extend the if-construct by an addtional elsif.

Comment: This is wrong. More constructs are supported. It also depended on the synthesis tool or compiler